# How do you activate Google Maps JavaScript API v3 service?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

The tutorial doesn't say how to activate the Javascript API v3 service. It just says do it. My Google Developers Console screen doesn't match the screen they show in the written (probably out of date) tutorial.

There is no "Service" category for me to choose. I have a  "Terms of service" category which, when chosen, allows me to read the terms for this particular API but there is no action to be taken in that window. I have an API key and I have entered the code in my web page and placed my API key in it.

I get the following error message when loading the web page: "This page was unable to display a Google Maps element. The provided Google API key is invalid or this site is not authorized to use it. Error Code: InvalidKeyOrUnauthorizedURLMapError" and I think it may be because I have not been able to "activate" API v3 for this project.

I have tried the following:

1. Regenerating a key and using it immediately so I know it isn't that the key is over 24 hours old
2. Double checked my referrals
3. Accurately entered the name of the site where I am trying to make this work.

Answer (score 24):

You need to activate API from the Developer Console

[image: reach the maps api v3 on google cloud console]

click the 4^ and then click the "Enable API" blue button

[image]

Comment: Thank you aqquadro for those very clear instructions. I deeply appreciate your help. I am still getting the same message but at least I can eliminate the activation as the problem now. I will continue to examine the code.

Comment: Are you setup the "Allowed origin" to enable localhost? You can do that from the "Credentials" section of the Developer Console :)

Answer (score 13):

I wasted my time just because of confusion so i am answering here with updated screenshots to help in a better way.
[image]

[image]

[image]